# AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager is not available in version 16.1.1.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit, toolkitscriptmanager

I was facing a problem with backspace button while using MaskedEditExtender, that's why I upgraded the AjaxControlToolkit from v 4.1.60919.0 to the latest version n 16.1.1.0. But now I am facing a new error, we were implementing the toolkitscriptmanager but now I cannot find it, even in the solution there is no ToolkitScriptManager neither ScriptManager to be called. So what should I do?
To understand what I mean:

In web.config I am assembling the AjaxControlToolkit to cc1

```
<add tagPrefix="cc1" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
```

Whenever I use cc1 tag in my .aspx pages, element ToolkitScriptManager is not valid in the new version. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is intended. [ToolkitScriptManager was removed in v15.1](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v7.x-and-below#2---replace-toolkitscriptmanager-with-scriptmanager). Please follow [the upgrade guide](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v7.x-and-below) to resolve this issue.

Comment: `ToolkitScriptManager` was removed in v15.1, that means it does not exist in all subsequent versions, incuding v 16.1.1. `ScriptManager` is a part of ASP.NET. not an AJAX Control Toolkit. You should prefix it with `asp:`.

Comment: These links are included in the readme that opens when upgrading to the latest nuget package. That link in turn links to a microsoft blog that now responds with a 403.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-4-5-scriptmanager-improvements-in-webforms.aspx

This accepted answer should include the detail to solve the problem and not just link to another page that might go away at any time.

Answer (score 13):

What worked for me was changing this:

```
<ajaxToolKit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajaxToolKit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

To this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

My original tagPrefix is ajaxToolKit whereas OP prefix is cc1, but same concept.

Everything in my project worked like a charm after this.